# Adding field from another table to a complex query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following query which returns a result set consisting of questions, possible answers for those questions and the number of times each answer was chosen by a user:

```
SELECT  sq.question_id, sq.question_text, qo.question_option_id, qo.option_text, G.Total
FROM    dbo.survey_question sq
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.question_option qo 
ON sq.question_id = qo.question_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ra.question_id, ra.question_option_id, count(*) AS Total
 FROM dbo.form_response_answers ra
 GROUP BY ra.question_option_id, ra.question_id ) G
    ON G.question_id = sq.question_id AND G.question_option_id = qo.question_option_id
ORDER BY
sq.question_id
```

On each of these records I need to add a column for form_id which is found within a table called form_question. The form_question table also contains a question_id field which should be matched with the question_id fields shown in the query above. However, I am having a lot of trouble trying to add this in as I am still struggling with my queries. Can someone please help me a bit with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes are in comments.

```
SELECT  
    sq.question_id
    , sq.question_text
    , qo.question_option_id
    , qo.option_text
    , G.Total
-- ==================================================
    , fq.form_id
-- ==================================================
FROM dbo.survey_question sq
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.question_option qo 
    ON sq.question_id = qo.question_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        ra.question_id
        , ra.question_option_id
        , count(*) AS Total
    FROM dbo.form_response_answers ra
    GROUP BY ra.question_option_id
        , ra.question_id 
) G
    ON G.question_id = sq.question_id 
    AND G.question_option_id = qo.question_option_id
-- ==================================================
-- Switch this to LEFT JOIN if there is a chance that
-- there won't be a form_question result for your
-- survey_question record.
-- Also, if there are multiple form_question records
-- for a survey_question, you might get more rows than
-- you're looking for.
INNER JOIN dbo.form_question fq
    ON fq.question_id = sq.question_id
-- ==================================================
ORDER BY sq.question_id
```